# ldapsearch does not return when ldaps is used

Tags: ldap

when I try in my test lab to do a

`ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://ldap.server.com`

it just sets there and return nothing. But when when I put

`10.10.10.10    ldap.server.com`    in    `/etc/hosts`

and do a

`ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.server.com`

I do get something like

```
# search result
search: 2
```

How can I get ldaps to work too? Thank you

Comment: The default port for LDAPS URLs is 636 instead of 389 (or another one depending on your conf), try to append it to the hostname : `ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://ldap.server.com:636`.

Comment: If I use 636, nothing happens, in case 389 I get `Can't contact LDAP server`

Answer (score 1):

This is two questions:

- why does adding to `/etc/hosts` help and
- why doesn't ldaps work when ldap does.

Unfortunately, you didn't post what happens with ldap but without the `/etc/hosts` entry, or with ldaps and with the `/etc/hosts` entry.

Also, you don't tell us which ldap server you're using, so i can only assume it's openldap.

To get the whole thing working without `/etc/hosts`, you'll have to get your name server entries right. Note that you get a hen-and-egg problem if `ldap` is your first entry for host resolution in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, so you can't avoid the `/etc/hosts` entry if `ldap` comes before `dns` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, and you need to put `hosts` in front of `ldap` there. But i guess you don't want to investigate that much further when the `/etc/hosts` entry fixes that part of your problem.

There's a good [FAQ on openldap with SSL](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/185.html) in the documentation. Basically, it boils down to:

- You need a SSL server certificate on your ldaps server
- your client needs to recognize the CA that issued the server's certificate
- you have to tell the server to support ldap AND ldaps when you start it.

Comment: @Buntram, Thank you very much, I will look in to documentation. I would like to, but don't know how to answer all your questions. Basically I am trying to figure it out how SSSD works with LDAP Authentication (http://www.refamco.ca/14-howto-rant/14-centos-6-4-ldap-authentication)... stuck at command `ldapsearch -x -H "ldaps://ldap.stratus.local"`